# Talend build job programmatically

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend ecosystem, I started with Talend Open Studio. I have managed to create, build, and run a build from the IDE, does anybody know if it is possible to build the job from the command line?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talend Open Studio does not allow you to build jobs from the command line, that's a feature of the subscription edition of Talend which has a commandline module.